# How to find sum of diagonal elements of a 4x4 matrix? When each element is one of number 1,2,...,16 and not same..

Tags: number-theory

Numbers 1, 2, 3, ⋅⋅⋅, 15, 16 are arranged on a 4 x 4 square. For i = 1, 2, 3, 4, let bi be the sum of numbers in the i-th row and ki is the sum of numbers in the i-th column. For example, also d1 and d2 are the numbers of the two diagonals. The arrangement can be called Antimagic if b1, b2, b3, b4, k1, k2, k3, k4, d1, d2 can be arranged into ten consecutive numbers. Determine the largest number among the ten consecutive numbers that can be obtained from an Antimagic.

for example: [this is an Antimagic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLWvL.png).

My idea is to add up all the numbers of antimagic. Because the arrangement of Antimagic is a arithmetic sequence:
a, a + 1, ..., a + 9.
So the sum of the sequence is 5 (2a + 9) = 10a + 45.
We know that b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 = k1 + k2 + k3 + k4 = 1 + 2 + ... + 16 = 136. But, I have no idea about d1 and d2.

Comment: "the number of numbers in the $i$-th row" is four. Did you mean the *sum* of the numbers in the $i$-th row? Can you please edit the question? Similarly for the columns.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, i have edited it. So, how about the answer?

Comment: so, there is no answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the largest number amongst the 10 was larger than 39. Then the sum of the 10 numbers would be at least $31+\dots+40=355$. Excluding the diagonal totals would give a total of at least $355-39-40=276$. But the four row totals must add up to 136, and so must the four column totals, giving a total of 272 for those eight numbers. So the largest number cannot exceed 39. Your example shows that 39 is possible.

Comment: I need an answer without assuming that 39 is the biggest number. Because it takes a long time to find an antimagic.

Comment: I didn't assume that 39 is the biggest number. I just showed a larger number doesn't work.

Comment: Incidentally, there are less than a 1000 4x4 magic squares (excluding rotations etc), so it would be easy to write a short computer program to find all antimagic squares.

Comment: but how you find number "39"?

Comment: The average row total is 34. So 34 must be near the middle of the group of 10 numbers. You cannot have the same number greater and less than 34. If 39 is the largest you have five greater than 34 and four less than 34.

Comment: so is this not direct proof?

Comment: You know like combinatorial or number theory

Comment: It's a proof using intelligence and common sense. These are indispensible tools in all branches of mathematics.

Comment: yeah.. it's uses contradiction.. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that there's a better way, Nlad?

Comment: Are you still here, Nlad?